# Using grouper to plot subset of dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, plot, plotly

I am using plotly express to plot a figure.

I have a dataframe that has a datetime value as the index that looks like:

```
index         account           A       B    NH        alloc
2021-10-13 16:00:50 sysadmin    1       2   4.0025      True
2021-10-13 21:28:43 sysadmin    1       3   0.0197      True
2021-10-14 08:11:29 phase1      1       4   0.0006      False
2021-10-14 08:06:13 sysadmin    1       5   0.2303      True
2021-10-14 08:20:07 sysadmin    1       6   0.0050      True
... ... ... ... ... ... ... ...
2021-11-03 15:40:22 phase1  1       2036    29.2364     False
2021-11-06 10:03:46 phase1  1       1894    48.0017     True
2021-11-06 12:36:41 phase1  1       1896    48.0039     False
2021-11-06 15:50:49 phase1  1       1895    48.0031     True
2021-11-06 16:50:25 phase1  1       1901    48.0014     False
```

I am using grouper to sum the values of NH over a 6H period. I would like to plot them for that period, in a bar chart stacked and coloured by the sums of the df[df["alloc"]==True] and df[df["alloc"]==False].

At the minute I have:

```
import plotly.express as px
fig = px.bar(x=df.groupby([pd.Grouper(freq="6H")]).sum()['NH'].index,
                 y= [ df[df["alloc"]==False].groupby([pd.Grouper(freq="6H")]).sum()['NH'],
                      df[df["alloc"]==True].groupby([pd.Grouper(freq="6H")]).sum()['NH']],
                title='NHTEST',barmode = 'stack')
    
    
 fig.show()
```

Which works fine if I am plotting the whole df, but not the subsets based on whether alloc==True, as the number of the x indices doesnt match the number of values returned by the grouper:

```
All arguments should have the same length. The length of argument `y` is 908, whereas the length of  previously-processed arguments ['x'] is 1493
```

Does anyone know how best to get what I am after (i.e. something like the following, where red is the sum of NH for that 6H period for `alloc==true` and blue is for `alloc==false`):

[image: desired plot]

Comment: An "Hacky" fix could be to create 2 new series, one with the product of `df[NH]*df[alloc]` the other with `df[NH]*(~df[alloc])`, then group and plot. Since you are adding the values in NH, multiplying them by 0 will not change the result, and you get lined up indexes

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out. Create the figure with px.bar, then add the second trace with fig.add_bar:

```
fig = px.bar(x=df[df["alloc"]==False].groupby([pd.Grouper(freq="6H")]).sum()['NH'].index,
             y=df[df["alloc"]==False].groupby([pd.Grouper(freq="6H")]).sum()['NH'],  
            labels={         "x": "Date", "y": "NH",
                 },
            title='testNH',barmode = 'stack')
fig.add_bar(name="Alloc",x=df[df["alloc"]==True].groupby([pd.Grouper(freq="6H")]).sum()['NH'].index,
             y=df[df["alloc"]==True].groupby([pd.Grouper(freq="6H")]).sum()['NH'])


fig.show()
```